# Executing Java app from PHP and returning a byte array of a calculation to PHP

Tags: java, php, ipc

I have written a php web app (front end) that allows a user to enter inputs and perform a certain calculation, I have written a java app that does the actual calculation (back end processing). The user input and clicks on a button to start the calculation, this invokes the java app via exec() function of php ( exec("java -jar biometrics.jar $param1",$output)). I want the results of the calculations done on the java app to be stored in a byte array and become accessible on the php side.

How can i do such ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edit your question: 
What did you try so far?

Comment: _Is there a way of doing this?_ Yes, it is.